# Google Play "can't establish a reliable connection to the server"

Tags: google-play-store

I have tried all methods to make Google Play work but it still says this:

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: It may be useful for other users if you could add some additional information to your question, for example which device you're using.

Comment: It may be a little too late to answer but this occasionally happens when the server certificate couldn't be verified on your device due to some date/time inconsistency. Try setting your device date/time to the proper value first.

Comment: i definitely have this problem with 4.1 devices.  It's a tough one. Very annoying.  I can't visit ordinary web sites like google.com because the cert is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If you have root, try to delete your hosts file in /system/etc/hosts.

Back it up first.

Comment: That might be helpful to someone (IDK really). But could you mention the reason why this file is supposed to be deleted at all?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know why it helped me. Even if my hosts file were empty and the Play Store couldn't connect, it always worked again after deleting the hosts file (on Samsung and on Asus).

Comment: Interesting! Did you need a reboot after deleting it or it worked just after deleting it?

Comment: I didn't need to reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Ah!  One thing that can cause this problem is simply

## Be sure to set the date and time, especially the year

on the device.  I had two devices laying around that had this problem.

On one the year was way out since it had been powered down for ages. I set the year and it was fine.

On another surprisingly it was

## only out by the time zone

I had it set 6 time zones away.  **Fixing the time zone, fixed the problem.**
Both of these were 4.1 devices (writing in Feb26; Android 6 is current now.)

Really hope it saves someone some time.

Answer (score 0):

Hey men try to factory reset your device, if not work uninstall update the google play and install with other version of google play ithink that should work...

Answer (score 0):

It may be the package problem. I hope you've tried all the methods for solving the problem so I will give you a manual way to use Play Store.
Below are the links for XDA-Developers (for reference) and Google Play (.apk) file which was featured on XDA-Developers website last week. See if it works.
* [XDA-Dev Get it now!](http://www.xda-developers.com/get-it-now/)
* [Google Play v5.5.12](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-store/google-play-store-5-5-12-android-apk-download/)